# padding in conv2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using the following code in keras

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
    
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
    
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    
# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
```

However if i use the second last Conv2D block:

```
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
```

with `padding='same'` the code gives me error . I dont understand how padding being same is problematic. If i remove this padding line, the code works fine. Any one please?

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because 'same' behaves inconistantly with `strides !=1`. Have you tried specifying strides as 1?
The issue is discussed in details [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9473#issuecomment-372166860)

Comment: if i add a strides=(1,1), with padding='same' then i get error: 
  Error when checking target: expected conv2d_14 to have (32,32,1) but got array   with shape (28,28,1)

without padding and strides=(1,1) is working but then again , the code without padding and no strides was working. So is the other Conv2D blocks in the code above where i think there is no strides defined, only filters and kernel size??

Answer (score 0):

```
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)


# at this point the representation is (7, 7, 32) 

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
```

Now if I use the above code I don't need to omit the padding='same' from second last conv2D block and its working